# How to remove digits based on their length

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I only want it to remove if multiple numbers in a row is found greater than 2 in a row in string.

Example, 780 <-- 3 digits, 4880 <-- 4 digits (would remove these from string)

But if 2 digits, example 24 <-- digits, it does not remove

Example, if text is

```
Dell Model 23506 Laptop M2
```

How to write replace function to remove the "23506" from above, so the end result is:

```
Dell Model Laptop M2
```

Example script template

```js
var item = "Dell Model 23506 Laptop M2";

var item2 = replaceAll(item, XXNUMBERSTOREMOVEXX, "");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) with [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const item = "Dell Model 23506 Laptop M2";
const item2 = item.replace(/\d{3,}/g, "");
console.log(item2)
```

- `\d{3,}` - 3 or more `d`igits

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Although you should accept the other answer which is much cleaner, here is my approach:

```
function myFunction() {

  const item = 'Dell Model 23506 Laptop M2';
  const numbers = item.match(/(?<=\s+).\d+(?=\s+)/gs)[0]; 
  const item2 = numbers.length>2?item.replace(numbers, ""):item;   
  Logger.log(item2);
}
```